# overrid FOS Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I try to override FOS bundle.

To do this I have:

UserBundle that I have created when intalling FOS. It have my User.php file.

UserBundle.php:

```
<?php

namespace gestEntrSym\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent() {
    return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

views/Default/layout.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Acme Demo Application{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ block('fos_user_content') }}
{% endblock %}
```

then I have app/Ressources/Views/base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
                {{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': app.user.username}, 'FOSUserBundle') }} |
                <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">
                    {{ 'layout.logout'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
                </a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}">{{ 'layout.login'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        {% for type, messages in app.session.flashBag.all %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="{{ type }}">
                    {{ message|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

        <div>aaa
            {{ block('fos_user_content') }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have now in the page just a link "Connexion", which just link to the page login. I want to have all the inputs in my layout page.

How can I do that?

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override your login template, create the folder

> app/Resources/FosUserBundle

and then respect the structure of the vendor folder which you won't toutch, so your overriden login wil be here :

> app/Resources/FosUserBundle/Views/Security/login.html.twig

Then if you want to include that template in base,

```
{% include('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig') %}
```